# Programmatic HTTP Post

Tags: javascript, java, html, http-post

I want to programmatically do HTTP post by parsing the below URL.

I am parsing the HTML Form parameters and then trying to post but it seems there is another parameter being added in runtime called metadata1 which is not there in the form.

Can someone help me how to figure out metadata1 ?

https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=inflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26action%3Dsign-out%26path%3D%252Fgp%252Fyourstore%252Fhome%26ref_%3Dnav__gno_signout%26signIn%3D1%26useRedirectOnSuccess%3D1

Comment: If it's not in the URL, how are we supposed to know what it is?

Comment: if you click open the url in my question - there is html form ... when i fillin userid / password on browser it runs some javascript which determines another hiddle html form parameter . I need to figure that out programmatically